# How does jquery proxy work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am more curious than anything else. How does it pass the context to the function. Does it wrap the function in the object? I am sure there is some simple straightforward code for doing this in js without jquery proxy

```
function abc(){
  console.log(this.name);
}
var obj={name:"Something"};
$.proxy(abc,obj);
```

How can I do this without jquery proxy?

Comment: ah when people come and downvote without bothering to leave a comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without jQuery you may use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) :

```
var newFunction = abc.bind(obj);
```

And if you want to be compatible with IE8, you may do

```
var newFunction = function(){ abc.call(obj) };
```

Here's how jQuery does it :

```
// Bind a function to a context, optionally partially applying any
// arguments.
proxy: function( fn, context ) {
    var args, proxy, tmp;

    if ( typeof context === "string" ) {
        tmp = fn[ context ];
        context = fn;
        fn = tmp;
    }

    // Quick check to determine if target is callable, in the spec
    // this throws a TypeError, but we will just return undefined.
    if ( !jQuery.isFunction( fn ) ) {
        return undefined;
    }

    // Simulated bind
    args = core_slice.call( arguments, 2 );
    proxy = function() {
        return fn.apply( context || this, args.concat( core_slice.call( arguments ) ) );
    };

    // Set the guid of unique handler to the same of original handler, so it can be removed
    proxy.guid = fn.guid = fn.guid || jQuery.guid++;

    return proxy;
},
```